# XPath expression for javax.xml.xpath not working

Tags: java, html, xpath, javax.xml

I want to extract the contents from this website: https://it.projektwerk.com/de/projects/

e.g. I have an XPath expression: `.//*[@id='content_0']/H3/A`
(Note that the uppercase letters are correct, as my document-parser -> org.cyberneko.html ... parses the tags to those uppercase ones)

This is a valid XPath expression; I can get the content using FirePath for example. However, using the `javax.xml.xpath` classes, the retrieval is not possible. I'm doing it like this:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(exprString);
Node node = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

but `node` is always `null`.

I don't get this, as there are other websites with other expressions of the same syntax, where that is working (e.g. `.//*[@id='p_p_id']/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV[3]/A/H3/SPAN`)

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Usually, HTML elements are in the HTML namespace—that is, the namespace whose URI is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.  You’ll need to call [xpath.setNamespaceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext-javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext-) to make that namespace known to the XPath engine, then change your expression to something like `.//*[@id='content_0']/html:H3/html:A`.

Comment: Thanks VGR, that helped me get to the solution, see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to VGR I was able to get to know the problem. The website, where those Xpath expressions were not working, was a namespace aware website with a html tag constructed like this:

As I am using [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), I used the following code:

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
props.setNamespacesAware(false);
TagNode mainNode = cleaner.clean(htmlString);
```

which should, according to the documentation, strip the namespace attributes from the html document. But this does **not** work! Surprisingly, the xmlns attribute inside the html tag of the tested html document will only change its position inside the list of attributes.
So the solution was to manually remove the xmlns attribute from the htmlTag using the HtmlCleaner's TagNode representation of the html node:

```
public TagNode removeNamespaceFromHtmlTag(TagNode htmlNode) {
    htmlNode.removeAttribute("xmlns");
    return htmlNode;
}
```

Removing this, the XPath expression defined in the question will return the desired result.